# Why creating an if condition after an if-else condition?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I try to understand and apply [nested Monte Carlo Research](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~cazenave/papers/nested.pdf). Yet, after reading its designer's paper I didn't understood why he added an if after an if-else condition. Shouldn't the last if be always skipped ?

Indeed, in `nested(position, level)` we can find at line 3 and 5 if and else conditions. When would the second if condition on line 7 would be read then ?

[image: nested part of Monte Carlo function]

Comment: Unfortunately, programming questions are off-topic here. It could to be on-topic on [SO], although I'm not sure whether it is a good question for that site either. You could try to flag this question for moderator to get your question migrated to [SO].

Comment: I don't understand your question. Read the code and isn't it obvious what it does? Lines 3-6 set "move" according to either one condition or another. Then, if the move (however it was set) is the best that has been found, something is done. Unless you misread it, what is there to not understand?

Comment: @Discretelizard I'm not sure this is really an SO question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Neither am I, but I'm pretty sure it isn't a CS question. I flag it for mods so that they can help determining that.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the `if-else` and `if` are not correlated. They are executed independently.

This structure would perhaps explain better:

```
if
 -- statement 1
else
 -- statement 2
end

# END OF IF ELSE BLOCK

if
 -- statement 3
end
```

Comment: This question is clearly off-topic for this site. Instead of answering here, _flag_ the question as off-topic and/or request a mod to migrate to [SO]. You can also inform the question asker that this is off-topic here (and where the question should go!). Feel free to answer the question after it has migrated/moved to the appropriate site

Comment: As I said in my comment to the question, I'm not at all convinced that the question is on-topic at SO. Also, even if a question is going to be migrated, there's no reason to wait until that has actually happened before answering. Migration says that the question is good, just in the wrong place; if the question is good, it should be answered.

Answer (score 0):

At line 4 and 6 you have an affectation with $move$ at left side, so an execution of that if else can modify $move$. At line 7, you have a test implying $score \ of \ move$, i don't know this notation but i guess that we get the score of the calculated move.

Thus, line 7 is here to test the new value of move provided by lines 4-6.

Comment: This question is clearly off-topic for this site. Instead of answering here, _flag_ the question as off-topic and/or request a mod to migrate to [SO]. You can also inform the question asker that this is off-topic here (and where the question should go!). Feel free to answer the question after it has migrated/moved to the appropriate site